# Borland Compiler's /NODEFAULTLIB equivalent?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

Is there a /NODEFAULTLIB equivalent for Borland's C++ compiler?

Their standard library is like 70kb big and very bloated. I'd like to get rid of it

Comment: Did you accidentally step in a time machine from the past? :P

Comment: :( Borland is still fun xD

Comment: Try reading the compiler documentation?

Comment: Doesn't mention anything about removing the standard library, however I find it unlikely that the ability isn't included or a hackish solution isn't available